# $\arg (z) < 0$ , then $\arg (- z) - \arg (z)$ =

Tags: complex-numbers

If  $\arg (z)  <  0$ ,  then  $\arg (- z) - \arg (z)$  = ?
Concept used

Principal Value

1. Quad I = $\alpha$
2. Quad II = $\pi -\alpha$
3. Quad III = $-\pi+\alpha$
4. Quad IV = $-\alpha$

Case 1: As $\arg(z) <0$, let us presume $z$ lies in QUADRANT II, therefore $-z$ lies in QUADRANT IV, therefore $A=\arg(-z) = -\alpha$ and $B=\arg(z)=\pi -\alpha$

$$A-B=-\pi.$$

Case 2: As $\arg(z) <0$, let us presume $z$ lies in QUADRANT IV therefore $-z$ lies in QUADRANT II , therefore$ A=\arg(-z)=\pi -\alpha$ and $B=\arg(z)=-\alpha$,

$$ A-B=\pi$$

Where I am making mistake?

Comment: What is $\alpha$?  How are you defining $\arg$?  that is, is $\arg$ the principal argument, or just some branch of the argument?  Also `\arg` will produce a properly formatted $\arg$.

Comment: $arg(z)<0$ this is the only condition we gave

Comment: $\alpha$ represent the angle representation w.r.t Co-ordinate in terms of principal values

Comment: It seems the formulas are correct if $\alpha = \tan^{-1}\left|\frac{y}{x}\right| \in [0, \frac{\pi}{2})$, where $z = x+i y$. Note that $\arg(z)<0$ occurs only when $z$ is in the 3rd and 4th quadrants.

Comment: @Gribouillis arg(z)<0 in 2&4 Quadrant, tan value

Comment: What definition of $\arg(z)$ do you have ?

Comment: The framer of this question has provided only the info presented in question rest is my assumption, the heading is complete question, my assumption can be wrong but question is correct. With respect to arg(z) i am confused whether we need negative tan value or negative angle value

Comment: Negative argument means negative angle. The argument of a complex number is its angle with the $x$-axis. Problems arise because an angle is only defined modulo $2\pi$.

Comment: $https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/174154/how-to-get-principal-argument-of-complex-number-from-complex-plane$ may be this will solve the problem arg(z)<0 $\in$ (-π/2,0) considerint principal value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter that $\arg z<0$. Consider

$$
z=|z|e^{i\theta}\\
$$

Now,

$$-z=|z|e^{i(\theta\pm\pi)}=|z|e^{i\tilde\theta}$$

where $\tilde\theta=\arg(-z)$

Then

$$\arg(-z)-\arg(z)=\tilde\theta-\theta=\pm\pi$$

This has been verified numerically for random values of $z$.

Comment: But answer is π and not -π, i cross checked it z lies in IV Quadant

Comment: That is correct, when $z$ is in the $4^{th}$ quadrant the result is $+\pi$. I have resolved the problem to $\pm\pi$. The rest is easy.

Comment: Because arg(z) $\in (-π,π]$ & tan z values is (-π/2,π/2) then Quadrant IV is the location

Comment: Excellent concept but one problem you cannot multiply by -π because arg (z) $\in$ (-π,π] it is open at -π but closed at π